# How to extend refinerycms controller with decorators?

Tags: refinerycms

I have generated an extension called Doctors.

I'm trying to extend the default functionality with  a decorators using the following the following guide http://refinerycms.com/guides/extending-controllers-and-models-with-decorators.

decorator:

```
Refinery::PagesController.class_eval do

    before_filter :find_doctors, only: [:doctors]

    protected

    def find_doctors
      @find_doctors = Refinery::Doctors::Doctor.all
    end      

end
```

if I replace [:doctors] for [:home] I can see the objects in the homepage but I want to show the items in the Doctor index view.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your code, you are trying to run the '**find_doctors**' method before the action '**doctors**' in **Refinery::PagesController** but the action '**doctors**' does not exist in **Refinery::PagesController**.

Replacing [:home] instead of [:doctors] works for homepage because the action 'home' does exist in **Refinery::PagesController**.

So, what you need to do is decorate **Refinery::DoctorsController** instead of Refinery::PagesController and run **find_doctors** method before **index** for index view.

```
Refinery::DoctorsController.class_eval do

   before_filter :find_doctors, only: [:index]

   protected

   def find_doctors
     @find_doctors = Refinery::Doctors::Doctor.all
   end
end
```